# Having trouble with variable not getting printed and \n not working

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, string-formatting

I am trying to make a ticket program. Here is my code:

```
public class CODE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many people? ");
        int people = input.nextInt();
        int cost =(int) (2.50*people);
        int x=0;

        System.out.println("---------------------- \n");
        System.out.printf("People:",people,"\n");
        System.out.printf("Total cost:$",cost,"\n");
        System.out.println("---------------------- \n");
    }
}
```

It asks me how many people, then it prints something very different than what I want it to print. If I were to type 4 people this is what will come out.

```
How many people? 
4
---------------------- 

People:Total cost:$----------------------
```

I want it to print (The 4 is the input I put in)

```
How many people?
4
---------------------- 
People:4
Total cost:$10
----------------------
```

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc for [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) ?

Comment: No java just told me to change println to printf, thanks I will read it.

Comment: Yes. Printf is rarely used because (I was taught) it's a convenience function for C programmers, so it's non-obvious syntax. An IDE might suggest it if it sees multiple parameters in a System.out call. Most common is to use just regular concatination and System.out.println.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see an extra newline because of:

```
System.out.println("---------------------- \n");
```

`println()` will produce a newline. The `\n` produce a second newline, hence pushing down the line 2 times.

There is no need to use print `printf` and `println`. Just do:

```
System.out.println("----------------------);
System.out.println("People:" + people);
System.out.println("Total cost:$" + cost);
System.out.println("----------------------);
```

Comment: Maybe because you didn't explain why the printf statements didn't work, which was the primary complaint in the question?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Printf` you need to put in a place holder for the variables.

```
System.out.printf("People: %d" ,people);
System.out.printf("Total cost:$ %d", cost);
```

Where `%d` is a placeholder for an `int`.

Or you can just do this:

```
System.out.println("People: " + people);
System.out.println("Total cost: $" + cost);
```

Read more on `printf` [here](https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet).

Comment: The extra "\n" in your println statements will do a double-newline.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Good catch. Thanks

Comment: So, your answer is similar to mine and someone downvoted me for no apparent reason.

Comment: @user3437460 Sorry, I hate downvoters who leave no reason. I'll upvote it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't know that because I am new to java. By the way, why is it %i? On a video, they used %d instead.

Comment: @TheCoder The  `%d` represents an integer.